# Растянуть блок на всю ширину экрана внутри родителя, который имеет заранее неизвестный margin-left

Tags: css

Возможно ли реализовать сабж? Есть список ul, в нем есть li (допустим .parent), заранее неизвестного уровня вложенности. Мне необходимо внутри li создать блок .child, ширина которого будет равняться ширине экрана, или какого то иного родительского контейнера для ul, но при этом чтобы .child оставался на одном уровне со своим .parent. Спасибо

Comment: Было бы замечательно если бы к вопросу прилагался бы пример, например с codepen.io, тогда бы вам ответили бы быстрее

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко пример в данном случае - это уже решение, которое я ищу :)

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко codepen здесь запрещён, для таких вещей есть сниппеты

Comment: Тогда скажите, для чего это все нужно. Может можно сделать более проще.

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov нарисуйте тогда картинку что ли, а то лично я текст этого вопроса как-то плохо воспринимаю)

Comment: Парни, могу показать картинку. Я примерно понимаю, как реализовано решение там, но так как мне откатываться назад для переделки крайне неохота, пытаюсь проскочить дуриком :) Я хочу добавить в свой список вот такую синюю подложку на всю ширину блока. типа вставить какой то то div, который по умному расползется на всю ширину экрана на своем уровне вложенности и вуа ля :) НА картинке видимо реализован динамический паддинг, который двигает  контент своего уровня формально оставаясь на всю ширину экрана. http://www.warmforestflash.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/project_template_expanded.gif

Comment: По вашей ссылке дерево проекта. Это точно то, что вы хотели показать?

Comment: @SergeyNovikov ну да, дерево, вложенность ul li, я хочу в каждый li попробовать добавить слой синего цвета, который будет являться фоном для контета каждого уровня дерева

Comment: не работает ссылка

Comment: работает, все норм, проверил

Comment: Все что показано на картинке, это древо.
Если это нужно сверстать, то можете подложку сделать фоном для всего блока. 
Иначе вы придумываете велосипед, не понятно зачем.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю что это дерево. У меня уже есть готовое дерево, которое интегрировано в дизайн проекта, и мое дерево со своей версткой, дизайном и классами. И мне необходимо самой малой кровью добавить цвет бэку под каждым наименованием уровня, ради чего переверстывать все не хочу.

Answer (score 2):

```
.child { width: 100%; }
```

Растяни просто на 100% его

Comment: не, он растянет на 100 процентов исходя от левого края своего родителя - li, а так как li смещен вправо согласно древесной структуре - смещается и его потомок. Мне же нужно чтобы внутри li его дочерний элемент был на всю ширину экрана от его края, а не от левой границы родителя

Comment: Тогда вместо 100%, 100 vw

Answer (score 0):

Растянет на 100% экрана:

```
.child { width: 100vw; }
```

Comment: то же самое, написал выше